# SQL Запрос сложения элементов

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица заказов `id, customer_id, total, status, order_date`.
В таблице порядка 1.5 млн строк.
Необходимо сделать выборку 500 полей, с максимальным суммарным `total`, и чтоб `status` был `'success'`.

Как я понимаю, сначала нужно сложить все `total` у которых одинаковые `customer_id`, а дальше сделать выборку с сортировкой.

Собственно в таблице хранятся строки в подобном виде:

[image: Клиент для работы с MySQL]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш запрос:

```
SELECT
     customer_id,
     sum(total)
FROM orders
WHERE status = 'success'
GROUP BY customer_id
ORDER BY sum(total) DESC
LIMIT 500;
```

Comment: Спасибо, данный запрос выполняется в моей таблице 17 секунд, его можно как то оптимизировать?

Comment: @YevgenyIgnatyev могут помочь индексы на столбцах `status` и `customer_id`.